# Searching current directory and 1 subdirectory for files with .txt extension

Tags: perl

Using the 'ls -R' command in perl, what is the parameter to find files with a .txt extension under the current and 1 subdirectory? Also I how would I count the number of files and if the number is one or more do a block of code that opens the files one after the other as in a loop?

Answer (score 1):

`ls -R` is a shell command. In Perl, you can use other means, e.g. globbing:

```
for my $file (glob '*.txt */*.txt') {
    if (-f $file) {                          # only take files
        open my $FH, '<', $file or die "$!";
    } 
}
```